# Paypal Php Sdk - NotifyUrl is not a fully qualified URL Error

Tags: api, paypal, sdk

I have this code

```
$product_info = array();
if(isset($cms['site']['url_data']['product_id'])){  
    $product_info = $cms['class']['product']->get($cms['site']['url_data']['product_id']);
}
if(!isset($product_info['id'])){
    /*
    echo 'No product info.';
    exit();
    */
    header_url(SITE_URL.'?subpage=user_subscription#xl_xr_page_my%20account');
}

$fee = $product_info['yearly_price_end'] / 100 * $product_info['fee'];
$yearly_price_end = $product_info['yearly_price_end'] + $fee;

$fee = ($product_info['setup_price_end'] / 100) * $product_info['fee'];
$setup_price_end = $product_info['setup_price_end'] + $fee;
if(isset($_SESSION['discountcode_amount'])){    
    $setup_price_end = $setup_price_end - $_SESSION['discountcode_amount'];
    unset($_SESSION['discountcode_amount']);
}


$error = false;
$plan_id = '';
$approvalUrl = '';
$ReturnUrl = SITE_URL.'payment/?payment_type=paypal&payment_page=process_agreement';
$CancelUrl = SITE_URL.'payment/?payment_type=paypal&payment_page=cancel_agreement';

$now = $cms['date'];
$now->modify('+5 minutes');


$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
        $cms['options']['plugin_paypal_clientid'],     // ClientID
        $cms['options']['plugin_paypal_clientsecret']  // ClientSecret
    )
);

use PayPal\Api\ChargeModel;
use PayPal\Api\Currency;
use PayPal\Api\MerchantPreferences;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentDefinition;
use PayPal\Api\Plan;
use PayPal\Api\Patch;
use PayPal\Api\PatchRequest;
use PayPal\Common\PayPalModel;
use PayPal\Api\Agreement;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\ShippingAddress;

// Create a new instance of Plan object
$plan = new Plan();
// # Basic Information
// Fill up the basic information that is required for the plan
$plan->setName($product_info['name'])
    ->setDescription($product_info['desc_text'])
    ->setType('fixed');
// # Payment definitions for this billing plan.
$paymentDefinition = new PaymentDefinition();
// The possible values for such setters are mentioned in the setter method documentation.
// Just open the class file. e.g. lib/PayPal/Api/PaymentDefinition.php and look for setFrequency method.
// You should be able to see the acceptable values in the comments.
$setFrequency = 'Year';
//$setFrequency = 'Day';
$paymentDefinition->setName('Regular Payments')
    ->setType('REGULAR')
    ->setFrequency($setFrequency)
    ->setFrequencyInterval("1")
    ->setCycles("999")
    ->setAmount(new Currency(array('value' => $yearly_price_end, 'currency' => $cms['session']['client']['currency']['iso_code'])));
// Charge Models
$chargeModel = new ChargeModel();
$chargeModel->setType('SHIPPING')
    ->setAmount(new Currency(array('value' => 0, 'currency' => $cms['session']['client']['currency']['iso_code'])));
$paymentDefinition->setChargeModels(array($chargeModel));
$merchantPreferences = new MerchantPreferences();

// ReturnURL and CancelURL are not required and used when creating billing agreement with payment_method as "credit_card".
// However, it is generally a good idea to set these values, in case you plan to create billing agreements which accepts "paypal" as payment_method.
// This will keep your plan compatible with both the possible scenarios on how it is being used in agreement.
$merchantPreferences->setReturnUrl($ReturnUrl)
    ->setCancelUrl($CancelUrl)
    ->setAutoBillAmount("yes")
    ->setInitialFailAmountAction("CONTINUE")
    ->setMaxFailAttempts("0")
    ->setSetupFee(new Currency(array('value' => $setup_price_end, 'currency' => $cms['session']['client']['currency']['iso_code'])));
$plan->setPaymentDefinitions(array($paymentDefinition));
$plan->setMerchantPreferences($merchantPreferences);

// ### Create Plan
try {
    $output = $plan->create($apiContext);
} catch (Exception $ex){
    die($ex);
}

echo $output->getId().'<br />';
echo $output.'<br />';
```

Been working with paypal php sdk for some days now and my code stop working.
So i went back to basic and i am still getting the same damn error.

I am trying to create a plan for subscription but getting the following error: 
"NotifyUrl is not a fully qualified URL"

I have no idea how to fix this as i dont use NotfifyUrl in my code?

Could be really nice if anyone had an idea how to fix this problem :)

Thanks

Comment: FIX IS HERE: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/pull/1152 Replace lib/PayPal/Api/MerchantPreferences.php with: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/srjlewis/PayPal-PHP-SDK/78cdfc879da27b7c56f94964ac068d3894d09877/lib/PayPal/Api/MerchantPreferences.php

Comment: Thanks mate, used same fix as you linked to :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PayPal did a update to their API last night which has caused problem within their SDK.
They are sending back null values in their responses.

I MUST stress the error is not on sending the request to PayPal, but on processing their response.

BUG Report : https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/1151

Pull Request : https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/pull/1152

Hope this helps, but their current SDK is throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 6):

Use below simple fix.

Replace below function in vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Api\MerchantPreferences.php

```
public function setNotifyUrl($notify_url)
{
    if(!empty($notify_url)){
        UrlValidator::validate($notify_url, "NotifyUrl");
    }

    $this->notify_url = $notify_url;
    return $this;
}
```

If you get the same error for return_url/cancel_url, add the if condition as above.

Note: This is not a permanent solution, you can use this until getting the update from PayPal.

Answer (score 1):

From [the GitHub repo for the PayPal PHP SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/tests/PayPal/Test/Api/MerchantPreferencesTest.php#L94), I see that the error you mentioned is thrown when MerchantPreferences is not given a valid NotifyUrl.  I see you're setting the CancelUrl and ReturnUrl, but not the NotifyUrl.  You may simply need to set that as well, i.e.:

```
$NotifyUrl = (some url goes here)
$obj->setNotifyUrl($NotifyUrl);
```

Comment: Thanks Richie Thomas
Adding Notify Url does not fix the problem :)

Thanks srjlewis
I will wait on paypal fixing there problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason** **behind** **it**!

error comes from.

vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Validation\UrlValidator.php

line.

```
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("$urlName is not a fully qualified URL");
 }
```

FILTER_VALIDATE_URL: according to this php function.

INVALID URL: "http://cat_n.domain.net.in/"; // IT CONTAIN _ UNDERSCORE.

VALID URL:  "http://cat-n.domain.net.in/"; it separated with - dash

here you can dump your url.
vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Validation\UrlValidator.php

```
public static function validate($url, $urlName = null)
{ 
   var_dump($url);
}
```

And then check this here: https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_func_validate_url

you can check here what character will reason for invalid.